# How to perform same operation on non concurrent excel cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

I am trying to perform the same operation on excel on a range of non-concurrent cells.

Let's say I have range C:C, within this range I need to perform this operation `IF(ISNUMBER(C2),(C2*A2),(0))`. How do I make this perform the same operation over and over again for cells `C9`, `C16`, `C23` and so on, so I would end up with something like :
`IF(ISNUMBER(C2),(C2*A2),(0))+IF(ISNUMBER(C9),(C9*A9),(0))`

With the result posted in the one single cell which could be anywhere on the sheet.

Thanks,

Sal

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! In other words, do you want to apply the operation to every seventh row (probably the days of the week)? Are you sure that the Pivot Table is not suitable for this task?

Comment: Hi John, the range is not for days of the week, but for parameters, let's say I have Outcome 1, 2, 3, 4 etc... would the pivot table still work?

Comment: I think you are looking for the formula SUMIF

Comment: How about using the [**N() function**](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/n-function-a624cad1-3635-4208-b54a-29733d1278c9)? Like as `=N(B2)*N(C2) + N(B9)*N(C9) + N(B16)*N(C16)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want every seventh row from row 2 onwards

`=SUM(IF(ISNUMBER(A:A),A:A,0)*IF(ISNUMBER(C:C),C:C,0)*(MOD(ROW(A:A),7)=2))`

**Explanation**

`IF(ISNUMBER(A:A),A:A,0)` is a version of worksheet column `A` with any non-numeric cells replaced by zeroes. Similarly, for `IF(ISNUMBER(C:C),C:C,0)`.

`(MOD(ROW(A:A),7)=2)` is simply a full worksheet column of `TRUE` and `FALSE` according to whether the worksheet row number is part of the sequence 2,9,16,23,... or not.

Excel allows identically sized arrays to be multiplied together, with the result being an array of the same size with cells obtained by multiplying together the corresponding cells of the "input" arrays. Additionally, in Excel, multiplying a number by `TRUE` or `FALSE` is equivalent to multiplying by 1 or 0, respectively.

The alternative formula of

`=SUM(IF(ISNUMBER(C:C),A:A*C:C,0)*(MOD(ROW(A:A),7)=2))`

only works if **all** elements of column `A` are either empty or numeric. If **any** element (cell) of column `A` is text and the corresponding element of column `C` is a number, the corresponding element of the `A:A*C:C` will be `#VALUE!` meaning the `SUM` will also evaluate to this value.

**Note**

The formula given allows for use of the whole of columns `A` and `C`. You may not want to "quarantine" the whole of these columns. For example, if you knew that knew that you were never going to exceed, say 100, rows in your "sum" (so that the last row to be including would not be after row 695) you could modify it to

`=SUM(IF(ISNUMBER(A2:A695),A2:A695,0)*IF(ISNUMBER(C2:C695),C2:C695,0)*(MOD(ROW(A2:A695),7)=2))`